# Doubly Linked List QuickSort Implementation Problem

Tags: java, list, algorithm, data-structures, quicksort

I've implemented a classic Doubly Linked List:

```
class Node<T> {
    protected T data;

    protected Node<T> next, prev;
}

class DoublyLinkedList<T extends Comparable<T>> {
    protected Node<T> front;
    protected Node<T> back;
    protected int size;

    // methods
}
```

Now in order to be able to sort it I then added the following methods implementing a classic QuickSort algorithm:

```
public void sort(Comparator<T> comparator) {
    quickSort(front, back, comparator);
}

private void quickSort(Node<T> begin, Node<T> end, Comparator<T> comparator) {
    if (end != null && begin != end && begin != end.next) {
        var temp = partition(begin, end, comparator);
        quickSort(begin, temp.prev, comparator);
        quickSort(temp.next, end, comparator);
    }
}

private Node<T> partition(Node<T> begin, Node<T> end, Comparator<T> comparator) {
    var pivot = end.data;

    var i = begin.prev;
    Node<T> next;

    for (var j = begin; j != end; j = next) {
        next = j.next;
        if (comparator.compare(j.data, pivot) < 0) {
            i = (i == null) ? begin : i.next;

            swapData(i, j);
        }
    }

    i = (i == null) ? begin : i.next;
    swapData(i, end);

    return i;
}

private void swapData(Node<T> a, Node<T> b) {
    var temp = a.data;
    a.data = b.data;
    b.data = temp;
}
```

The code above produces correct results, however, I decided to swap the nodes instead of data, so I  introduced these methods:

```
private void swapNodes(Node<T> a, Node<T> b) {
    if (a == b) return;

    if (a == null || b == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException();
    }

    if (a.next == b) {
        var before = a.prev;
        var after = b.next;

        link(before, b);
        link(b, a);
        link(a, after);
    } else if (b.next == a) {
        var before = b.prev;
        var after = a.next;

        link(before, a);
        link(a, b);
        link(b, after);
    } else {
        var aPrev = a.prev;
        var aNext = a.next;
        var bPrev = b.prev;
        var bNext = b.next;

        link(aPrev, b);
        link(b, aNext);
        link(bPrev, a);
        link(a, bNext);
    }
}

private void link(Node<T> a, Node<T> b) {
    if (a != null)
        a.next = b;
    else
        front = b;
    if (b != null)
        b.prev = a;
    else
        back = a;
}
```

And added these changes to the `partition` method:

```
private Node<T> partition(Node<T> begin, Node<T> end, Comparator<T> comparator) {
    var pivot = end.data;

    var i = begin.prev;
    Node<T> next;

    for (var j = begin; j != end; j = next) {
        next = j.next;
        if (comparator.compare(j.data, pivot) < 0) {
            i = (i == null) ? begin : i.next;

            //swapData(i, j);
            swapNodes(i, j);
            i = j;
        }
    }

    i = (i == null) ? begin : i.next;
    //swapData(i, end);
    swapNodes(i, end);

    //return i;
    return end;
}
```

At this point the code is not working correctly and I can't figure out why. What am I missing?

**Edit:**

The expected output is the sorted input which in the second case it is not.

Example:

```
Initial :[2, 9, 8, 3, 6, 2, 4, 1, 7, 6]
Expected:[1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 6, 6, 7, 8, 9]
Actual:  [1, 3, 2, 4, 2, 6, 9, 6, 7, 8]
```

A working example can be found here: https://ideone.com/UQrzY1

**Edit2:**

Provided a shorter example and input/output.

Comment: How is it not working correctly? Please give us an input, the actual output. I assume the expected output is the sorted input. If you'd give us the complete code (including the imports and the main that you're testing with), I'd be able to put this into a debugger.

Comment: @NomadMaker, thanks, I supplemented the question with the necessary information.

Comment: In `link(...)` the code for `b == null` is incorrect, it is currently `back = b` but should be `back = a`. Not sure if there are other issues.

Comment: Code should be included in the question as text.

Comment: @Marcono1234, my bad, it's a typo, but it does not affect the end result in this case.

Comment: `I decided to swap the nodes instead of data` *Why on earth*? And why without  dummy/sentinel node(s) before and after the list? How did you *test* `swapNodes()`?

Comment: (`begin != end.next` deserves a comment.)

Comment: @greybeard, `Why on earth?` If I have iterators pointing to certain list elements, by swapping references instead of the actual nodes during sorting I will also change the values of those iterators. This is not the desired behavior. This is also how `std::list::sort()` works, for example.

Comment: @greybeard `And why without dummy/sentinel node(s) before and after the list?` I considered `null`'s to be sufficient enough for this implementation.

Comment: (Entirely unrelated: your ideone change to mergesort is one fine case for including essential material in stackexchange posts.)

Comment: Could you check and debug the `parition(...)` logic? It appears the local variables it is using point to the wrong nodes after nodes have been swapped. For some input values this even causes a `NullPointerException`, e.g. for `[2, 0, 1]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a reason the bug in the "swap-nodes variant" is hard to pin down:
You don't support debugging.
Make it a habit to have classes provide a basic `toString()`:

```
/** doubly linked list node */
static class Node<T> {
    …
   /** constructs a <code>Node</code> given data, next & prev */
    public Node(T d, Node…
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.valueOf(data);
    }
}
```

It's a bit more complicated with the lists -

```
    /** Append string representations of <code>node</code>s 
     * <code>data</code> to <code>head</code>, following 
     * <code>next</code>s til <code>end</code> (or <code>null</code>)
     * (inclusive)
     */
    Appendable append(Node<T> node, final Node<T> end,
        CharSequence separator, Appendable head) {
        try {
            while (end != node) {
                head.append(String.valueOf(node));
                if (null == node
                    || null == (node = node.next) && null == end)
                    return head;
                head.append(separator);
            }
            head.append(String.valueOf(node));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return head;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return ((StringBuilder)append(front, null, ", ",
            new StringBuilder("["))).append(']').toString();
    }

    void bug(String label, Node<T> node, final Node<T> end) {
        System.out.append(((StringBuilder)append(node, end, ", ",
            new StringBuilder(label).append('('))).append(")\n"));
    }
    String verbose(Node<T> n) {
        return "+" + n.prev + "<-" + n + "->" + n.next;
    }
    
    private void quickSort(Node<T> begin, Node<T> end, Comparator<T> comparator) {
        bug("quicksort", begin, end);
        if (end != null && begin != end && begin != end.next) {
            Node<T> temp = partition(begin, end, comparator);
            System.out.println("begin: " + begin + ", temp: "
                + verbose(temp) + ", temp == end: " + (temp == end));
            quickSort(begin, temp.prev, comparator);
            bug("between", begin, temp.prev);
            quickSort(temp.next, end, comparator);
        }
    }
```

Using above intrusive debugging, you can see that `end` doesn't stay the end of the right part - how would it being picked the pivot element in a Lomuto partition.
Nor does `begin` stay the beginning of the left part - you'd seem to need *successor of `begin`'s predecessor* and *predecessor of `end`'s successor* respectively.
Ensuing a wagonload of special cases without sentinel nodes before and after the list.